# Access token with Axios gets the following error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, axios

I'm trying to request the access token with Axios in my SpringBoot + React application.

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/oauth/access_token", 'grant_type=password&username='+username+'&password='+password,
    { headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("clientid:clientsecret"),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded,charset=UTF-8'
     }
```

But I'm always getting the following error: "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401".

I tried the request with Postman and it works always.

Thanks!

Comment: David, have you found my answer useful? You can consider accepting the answer, or write a comment, so I get some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, you are trying to use, is not suitable for JavaScript applications running in a browser, because you cannot keep the password safe in a browser. That's also the reason why the token endpoint (`/access_token` in your case) doesn't support CORS HTTP headers and the XHR request from your question fails.

Unlike browser, Postman doesn't require the CORS headers and doesn't issue the OPTIONS request before the actual request, so it works.

Try to use the Implicit grant flow which is designed for browser applications.